# WordPress Custom Taxonomies WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to create a query where I create multiple categories (taxonomies) in a custom post type, and then on the homepage query based on specific which is working fine. Currently I have 3 taxonomies:

1. current-specials
2. meineke-difference
3. featured

I have already written code that pulls these. The problem I'm running into is that on the homepage it needs to only pull these posts when they are also attached to the "featured" taxonomy. So an example of standard logic for this would be:

if taxonomy = current-specials AND featured then success else fail

But what it's doing is pulling them all because the current code is OR, and I need AND

Thoughts? (code below)

```
<?php

$post_type = 'coupons';
$tax = 'coupons_category';
$tax_terms = get_terms($tax);

if ($tax_terms):

    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term):

        echo '<div id="'.$tax_term->slug.'" class="coupon-box '.$tax_term->slug.'">';

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            "$tax" => array($tax_term->slug, 'featured'),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'caller_get_posts' => 1
        );
        $myQuery = null;
        $myQuery = new WP_Query($args);

        if($myQuery->have_posts()):
            while ($myQuery->have_posts()) : $myQuery->the_post();

            $price = get_field('price_image', $myQuery->ID);
            $print = get_field('print', $myQuery->ID);
            $product = get_field('product_box_image', $myQuery->ID);

            $title = get_the_title();
            $content = get_the_content();

            echo '<div class="fourty9 left box center">';
                echo '<h1>'.$title.'</h1>';
                echo '<p class="center"><img src="'.$price.'" /></p>';
                echo '<p>'.$content.'</p>';
                echo '<p class="center"><a href="'.$print.'">Print Coupon</a></p>';
                echo '<p class="center"><img src="'.$product.'" alt="Filter"></p>';
            echo '</div>';  


            endwhile;
        endif;

        echo '</div>';

        wp_reset_query();

    endforeach;

endif;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this (`tax` - use taxonomy slug. Deprecated as of Version 3.1 in favor of 'tax_query')

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'coupons',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'coupons_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'current-specials', 'featured' ),
            'operator' => 'AND'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Gave me a blank screen. I copied your $args array exactly.